# Bacula: best practise for labeling and initial start

Tags: backup, tape, bacula, lto

I'm currently starting with bacula for backup and have a few questions for best practices.

**Current situation:**

- I want to back up a slow changing max. 12TB (currently 8TB) dataset to a external LTO4 drive. Due to the small incremental changes I prefer the strategy to do a full backup every half a year and monthly incremental.
- The full backups should be done alternating to 2 pools so that one can be kept offsite
- I managed the config (see the bottom for relevant parts) and my testcases on disk base are looking good

**So here are the questions:**

- How can I tell bacula how many numeral digits should be used for autolabeling (default is 4)? As my prefix is 4 digits long and tapelabels (even if I currently don't need them) only support 6 digits, I want to force bacula to autolabel with 2 numerical digits (e.g. FS1T01 - 99) to keep consistency.
- Is it better practise to feed bacula the tapes on first backup run and let em do the labeling or to add them to the pool before running the job?

**relevant config extracts:**

Director:

```
Pool{
  Name = FullSet2
  Use Volume Once = yes
  Pool Type = Backup  
  LabelFormat = "FS2T"
  AutoPrune = yes
  VolumeRetention = 350 days
  Maximum Volumes = 15
  Recycle = yes
}

Pool{
  Name = FullSet1
  Use Volume Once = yes
  Pool Type = Backup  
  LabelFormat = "FS1T"
  AutoPrune = yes
  VolumeRetention = 350 days
  Maximum Volumes = 15
  Recycle = yes
}

Pool {
  Name = DiffSet
  Use Volume Once = yes
  Pool Type = Backup
  LabelFormat = "DS1T"
  AutoPrune = yes
  VolumeRetention = 1 day
  Maximum Volumes = 10
  Recycle = yes
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for 2)

I label a new tape on demand, when Bacula asks me to label one. But if I would know in advance that I will need 10 new tapes on that day then I would label all of them at once. Labelling a new tape is quite a simple thing.

1. You may want to get an overview about your tapes by first by issuing the `list volumes` command in Bacula console.
2. Unmount the current tape in the drive using the `umount` command in Bacula console and physically eject the current tape by pressing the button on the tape drive.
3. Put in the new, empty tape
4. Issue the `label` command in bconsole, select the pool, and enter the label you want or accept the label which is recommended by Bacula.
5. Issue `umount` and remove the tape
6. Write and affix a physical label too.
7. Go to 3 if you want to label another tape.

Answer (score 2):

as for 1)

Label Format = "FS1T${NumVols:p/2/0/r}"               # Auto label

This command pads with zeroes to  2 digits and puts the variable ${NumVols} (Number of volumes) to the right (r) of the max 2 digits.

Comment: Hello user993553, welcome on Serverfault. Please extend your answer and explain what this command does, what it is intended for, and why it is needed.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I would love to accept you both as correct answer, buts its impossible, so I decided to give it to Hontvari, as he currently has less reputation. Nevertheless your answer is exactly what I was looking for and you got my upvote!